# Missing product options in the order in OpenCart 1.5.4.1

Tags: opencart

From time to time some products in the order are missing required option (e.g. the color or the size). It can happen to one product in the whole order, or to some of them. Trying to replicate it didn't help. You cannot add a product to cart without selecting an option, but it does happen for some users.

Anyone have an idea what can cause it?

Comment: Do the options appear in the cart prior to submitting the order?

Answer (score 0):

If customer has order product before, and before time that you added option to product, customer has original product without option in his/her order history and can add it to cart thru the reorder, or if you have some "save cart" module customer can hav saved the product before and now add it to cart, both function bypass the validation.

/regards Markus
mefixit.se